# How to pass data to the activity that is prior to the previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activity, eg. A, B and C. A start B, and B start C. I will remove B from the back stack in C. Then I need to pass some data from C to A before I finish C. My question is how to pass data from C to A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass some data from C to A before finishing C activity then you can use broadcast receiver in your A activity and can send broadcast from C to A directly.

Write the below code before starting activity B from A. This code will receive data from activity C.

```
BroadcastReceiver brd_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("receive data from C")) {
            // DO YOUR WORK HERE.
        }

    }
};

registerReceiver(brd_receiver, new IntentFilter("receive data from C"));
```

Write this code to send data from activity C to activity A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("receive data from C");
        intent.putExtra(name, value); //SAVE YOU DATA INTO INTENT.
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope it will help you if it is not working then tell me the problem you are facing. I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class and make it as Singleton class. Then use setter and getter method to set the value from one class and get the value from other class.

```
public class SingletonObjectDemo {
private String value;
// use setter and getter here...


private static SingletonObject singletonObject;
// Note that the constructor is private
private SingletonObjectDemo() {
    // Optional Code
}
public static SingletonObjectDemo getSingletonObject() {
    if (singletonObject == null) {
        singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
    }
    return singletonObject;
}
```

}

Comment: I think this answer can solve my problem, but I prefer to use the android only features, so I will use BroadcastReceiver. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: @Leoguo If it solved your problem then you can mark this answer as Accepted So it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you startActivity by Intent to Go C from A then you can pass data through putExtra of intent.If you just go in C by pressing back then write your data in some common place like shared preference so that you can access from A

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Handler` to pass data from one activity to another Or you can start each activity using `startActivityForResult()`. Then by using `setResult(resultCode, data)` you can pass on the extra data to the previous activity which can by accessed in the function `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

Comment: This answer can solve my problem, but I need to change all theses activity, so I don't think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

try like this;;

In activity C..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), A.class);
intent.putExtra("Your_key-ID", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity A..

```
Intent sender=getIntent();
String extraData=sender.getExtras().getString("Your_key-ID");
```

ANd check this link

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/

Comment: The code above will start a new activity A from activity C, I think it is not correct.