# Update and refresh ListView item when another Activity finishes

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Scenario:
I have a `customAdapter`, a `feeditem` where I `set` and `get` data, a `ReplyActivity` and `MainActivity`.

`MainActivity` retrieve `data` from `server` and displyay it to `ListView` using the `customAdapter`. The `ListView` have `btnReply` which is shown in the `customAdapter` below and `onClick` `ReplyActivity` is opened.

On `ReplyActivity`, I have an `EditText` and a `Button`, after writing and `onButtonClick`, the `text` from `EditText` is `send` to `server` and then saved in `SharedPreferences` and `ReplyActivity` is closed by calling `finish()` without starting any `Activity`, this brings `MainActivity`to foreground where my `Adapter` is used. 
I already have a logic to detect if my `MainActivty` was brought to `foreground` by `finishing` `ReplyActivity`.

Now my issue, is how can I update just `repStatus` of the `position` where `btnReply` was `clicked` that leads to starting `ReplyActivity`?

I searched all the answers are not relevant to this scenario. Though, I came across [this here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643940/refresh-listview-after-updating-in-another-activity) but can not work in this case.

If anyone can help me on how I can do this or point me to any resources that can help me in achieving this will be highly appreciated.

My Adapter:

```
    public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//        session = new SessionManager(MediaActivity.class);
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
            convertView.setLongClickable(true);
        }

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final Button btnReply = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnReply);
        final TextView statusMsg = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        final TextView repStatus = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.repStatus);


    btnReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReplyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("statusId", statusId.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("username", userName.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
   } 
}
```

Comment: Don't track positions, track keys.

Comment: Can you please explain how? @Karakuri

Comment: Does your data have any sort of key or ID? Can your data structure be searched efficiently for an item with a given key/id? My answer would be to use `startActivityForResult()` and pass the key, not the position. Pass the key back when you set the result of the `EditActivity`, then in `onActivityResult()` look for the item with that key in your data structure and modify it accordingly, then notify the adapter that the data has changed.

Comment: Yes, each element of the list item is having a unique ID

Comment: How can I pass the key back to the Adapter? @Karakuri

Comment: You pass an extra in the `Intent` which starts the EditActivity, and you pass an extra in the result `Intent` that you provide when calling `setResult()` before finishing the EditActivity.

Comment: Let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried that, but onActivityResult() can not be implemented inside my adapter and that is the only way to update `repStatus`. @Karakuri

Comment: The activity has to implement it, but the activity has access to the adapter. Your problem is only code structure.

Comment: What I just did is: from my onClickListner inside the adapter, I saved all the items of the list element ( 20 in number), in sharedPref then on success after finishing the ReplyActivity I then used the position from sharedPref to delete that list element and then use same postion to add all the data in same position then I call notifyDataSetChanged(). I know its not the best way to do it but I have no option. THANKS FOR YOUR TIME AND ADVICE @Karakuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here -

The best practice one is to call `startActivityForResult(intent)` and override `onActivityResult()` callback method inside `MainActivity`.([guide here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html))

The second option is to set a ShardPreference `boolean firstTime = false` inside `ReplyActivity` and check inside override `onResume` inside `MainActivity` and check if this is first time or not. (`onResume` is being called any time acitvity UI is getting back to the front again - and also after `onCreat`)

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I have tried that but wont work. Just look at it again

Comment: The issue is how can I know the position of the item that I am altering?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the onResume method in your MainActivity after that you can have a public method in your adapter that you call in onResume

Note : OnResume will be called the first time right after the OnCreate method so be aware of that and find a way to tell difference between the first OnResume and the next OnResume calls that is triggered whenever your activity came to foreground

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I have tried that but wont work. Just look at it again

Answer (score 0):

You can use onResume() method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Check here if the text from edittext was saved in sharedpreference or not.

   // Refresh the adapter
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

Refer More here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

For updating repStatus:
Implement onListItemClick. Then, get the view by id and update it.

[Android ListView, OnListItemClick find all the views of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986835/android-listview-onlistitemclick-find-all-the-views-of-row)

Comment: Sorry I updated my question. I have tried that but wont work. Just look at it again

Comment: You can use SharedPreference for saving repStaus.

Comment: I have already done that. I mentioned that in the question. @Akshar

Comment: SharedPreference should work just fine or you can go with the solution given by @Karakuri

Comment: May be my English is bad that lead to non understanding of my question. Now my issue, is how can I update just repStatus of the position where btnReply was clicked that leads to starting ReplyActivity? @Akshar

Comment: Implement onListItemClick.  Then, get the view by id and update it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986835/android-listview-onlistitemclick-find-all-the-views-of-row

Comment: I already saw the link before asking the question. Thanks though for your effort. @Akshar